# Functionals taking real values

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $f$ is a bounded functional on a separable Hilbert space. Can we always find an orthonormal basis such that $f$ takes real values on that basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ is an orthonormal basis for your Hilbert space and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots \in \Bbb{C}$ with $|\lambda_1| = |\lambda_2| = \ldots = 1$, what can you say about $\lambda_1v_1, \lambda_2v_2, \ldots$ and about $f(\lambda_iv_i)$?

Comment: Yes, so embarrassingly obvious.